check existence, reading and writing of files in temporary:// with xslt in datapower
I have to check if a file named token.jsonx exists in the temporary:// directory, read it and replace it with a XSLT stylesheet in DataPower.
I tried to use the dp:url-open with
<dp:url-open target="'temporary:///token.jsonx'" response="xml" http-method="get" datatype="filename">temporary:///token.jsonx</dp:url-open>

, but I received the message
url-open: Unsupported URL ''temporary:///token.jsonx''

I tried to use the

document()

XSLT function with
document('temporary:///token.jsonx') 

but it fails if the file does not exists.
What did I do wrong ? Or how can I do ?
Thanks for your help !

change <dp:url-open target="'temporary:///token.jsonx'" to <dp:url-open target="temporary:///token.jsonx" ?
